# Flutter - change icon color when selected

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a tab bar and have the icons be gray while selected and go back to black when a different icon is selected. My problem is however that upon clicking on one of icons, it registers the click, but I don't understand why it doesn't change the color of the icons. Help would be greatly appreciated!

```
int buttonSelected = 1;

IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: buttonSelected == 1 ? Colors.grey : Colors.black,),
  onPressed: () {
    buttonSelected = 1;
    print('home');},
),

IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.message, color: buttonSelected == 2 ? Colors.grey : Colors.black,),
  onPressed: () {
    buttonSelected = 2;
    print('message');},
),
```

Comment: You need to call setState func when a Tab is Change.

Comment: You could also try option of TabBar that is TabBar(`labelColor: YourColor,
            unselectedLabelColor: YourColor,` )

Comment: use statefull widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `setState` to rebuild page

Make sure you are using **statefull** widget instead of **stateless** widget

```
int buttonSelected = 1;

IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: buttonSelected == 1 ? Colors.grey : Colors.black,),
  onPressed: () {
    setState(){ buttonSelected = 1;};
    print('home');},
),

IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.message, color: buttonSelected == 2 ? Colors.grey : Colors.black,),
  onPressed: () {
    setState(){ buttonSelected = 2;}; 
    print('message');},
),
```